# Hacked AWS account - how do I access/delete linked accounts that they have created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Our AWS account has been hacked due to someone wrongly supplying an Administrator level access key.

We didn't have an Organisation set up, but the attackers created one.  They have then created linked accounts within the organisation and created EC2 instances within them.

The problem I have is that I can't see any way to:

1. Delete the linked accounts (it says I need to add a payment method to the linked account)
2. View or terminate the EC2 instances on the other accounts

Can someone please tell me if it's possible to use my root login to access the EC2 instances on the linked accounts?  This is costing us a lot of money in the last few hours unfortunately.  I have a support case with AWS but they have mentioned that it could take 2-3 business days...

I have disabled users via IAM and made keys inactive.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The [aws docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/organizations-member-account-access/) explain how to accessed member accounts.

Comment: You should contact AWS Customer Service (which is different to AWS Customer Support) for [billing and account support](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/) and report the incident. They will be able to assist.

Comment: @Marcin thank you - that link eventually got me to a place where I was able to switch my user to one of the linked accounts. If you put it as an answer I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully AWS support will be able to wave the extra costs associated with those instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Since the OP already contacted the support, the one thing to do was to access the compromised accounts from the master account and disable the instances. The procedure to do it is explained in the AWS docs:

- [After I use AWS Organizations to create a member account, how do I access that account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/organizations-member-account-access/)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a AWS account in an Organization you set up a roles that the organization account can use to assume access into that account. If you can see what role is used for these accounts use that role and and assume access into it and take down what you need.

To get the concept of it better you can try to create your own account with organization and assume that role.

This should work as long as the hacker haven't done anything to the role.

Here is docs on how to do this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html